# JSF Print + Refresh Page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, printing

A point of sale application was built with JSF/JPA/Primefaces.

When the cashier print the bill, the page has to be directed to a new page, or else,cashier will be able to take reprint and cheat the management.

Primefaces printer controller is used, but when it prints, the action is not executed.

How can I print and after completion, direct to a new page by action command ?

I have tried the following methods

---

This Prints, but action is not executed nor directed to a page.

```
<p:commandButton value="Print" ajax="false" action="#{billController.prepareNewBill()}"  >
<p:printer target="gpBillPreview" ></p:printer>
</p:commandButton>
```

---

This also prints, but action is not executed. Page is also not directed.

```
<p:commandButton value="Print" update="@all" actionListener="#{billController.prepareNewBill()}"  >
    <p:printer target="gpBillPreview" ></p:printer>
</p:commandButton>
```

---

This also does not execute action, but if Iomit Printer, it reloads the page.

```
<p:commandButton value="Print" update="@all" action="#{billController.prepareNewBill()}"  oncomplete="location.reload();" >
    <p:printer target="gpBillPreview"  ></p:printer>
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: "*Cheat the management*"? :) Did you try putting some debugging statement(s) inside the action(Listener) method associated to make sure it is really invoked ? And you may also want to add either `process="@this"` or `type="button"` in this case - `update="@all"` is something which should not be needed on the other hand. You may also add PrimeFaces AJAX behaviour such as `oncomplete` and make a redirect using AJAX from the client-side such as your last case (`window.location.href = "URL";`).

Comment: I inserted System.out.println("") method inside and it is not executed. When a bill is printed, it prepares a new bill and previous bill details should be cleared.

Comment: I added                                                                                        <p:commandButton value="Print" process="@this" update="@all" type="button" action="#{billController.prepareNewBill()}"  >
        <p:printer target="gpBillPreview" ></p:printer>
</p:commandButton>                                                                                     But still it did not work.

Comment: I added to oncomplete (window.location.href = "URL";), yet it failed.

Comment: `action(Listener)` is not invoked in my attempts too. As a guess, the `action(Listener)` or `oncomplete` attached to a command component may be invoked after the print process is completed through the physical printer in question. Did you try using a physical printer machine printing  the target JSF components on a piece of paper? I do not have a printer and cannot  give it a try.

Comment: Tried with a physical printer, yet failed using firefox.